# C#: Using the String.Split method to split a list of string at each separate line?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I am trying to split my list of strings at each separate lines using the [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method but the both the method below and a regex method did not work. Instead, they returned the following result `{0}
0. System.String[]` instead of the actual array of strings. Please help to find the error(s) in the code below:

```
    string m_settings_temp;
    string[] m_settings;
    public void ShowSettingsGui() {
       var dialog = new OpenFileDialog { Filter = "Data Sources (*.ini)|*.ini*|All Files|*.*" };
       if (dialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
       m_settings_temp = File.ReadAllText(dialog.FileName);
       m_settings = m_settings_temp.Split(new [] { '\r', '\n' });
       //This regex method failed as well:  
       //m_settings = Regex.Split(m_settings_temp,"\r\n|\r|\n");
    }

    //The method below is to evaluate the output
    protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA)
                    {
                        if (m_settings == null)
                        {
                            AddRuntimeMessage(GH_RuntimeMessageLevel.Warning, "You must declare some valid settings");
                            return;
                        }
                        DA.SetData(0, m_settings);
                    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The methods return an array of strings - not a single string.

Comment: how many files do you choose to read ?

Comment: @Oded this is why I am declaring string[]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just use [`ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) like this

```
m_settings = File.ReadAllLines(dialog.FileName);
```

this will give you a `string[]` with an element for each line in the selected file. If, after running this code, `m_settings` has no elements, the file you selected was empty.

---

If I wanted to interrgoate the contents of `m_settings` in a console app I might do somthing like.

```
for (var i = 0; i < m_settings.Length; i ++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m_settings[i]);
}
```

This would output the content of array, one element at a time. If I used the implementation of `ToString` for am array, like this,

```
Console.WriterLine(m_settings);
```

I would get a string representation of the array's type and the number of elements it contains.

---

I suspect in your case you want to do somthing like

```
protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA)
{
     if (m_settings == null || m_settings.Length == 0)
     {
         AddRuntimeMessage(
              GH_RuntimeMessageLevel.Warning,
              "You must declare some valid settings");

         return;
     }

     for (var i = 0; i < m_settings.Length; i ++)
     {
         DA.SetData(i, m_settings[i]);
     }
}
```

Comment: +1 That is better than splitting it yourself. It keeps the code clean.

Comment: In some cases it's better to use File.ReadLines() (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503) which will let you enumerate over all the lines in a file WITHOUT storing them all in memory. This can be important for very large files.

Comment: Thanks a lot but I am still getting the `{0}
0. System.String[]` as output instead of the actual string array.

Comment: @arthurmani, how are you evaluating the ouput? You don't show that in your sample.

Comment: @Jodrell I have added the method to read the output in the question. Thank you very much for your replies.

Comment: @Jodrell thanks so much but I am getting the following message in my program: `Output parameter Index[1] too high or too low for Component LoadSettings.`

Comment: Okay, I don't know enough about `IGH_DataAccess` to tell you exactly what is right. I suspect your orginal code is more correct. Possibly, when you access the settings you will need to do somthing like `DA.GetData(0)[0]` but I am just guessing. It all depends how array values are treated by your component framework.

Comment: @Jodrell, the IGH_DataAccess is already providing an iteration count in the help it says `Gets the current iteration count. The first time the SolveInstance() function is called on a component during a solution the Iteration counter will be zero. It will be incremented by one for every subsequent call. ` When using `DA.SetData(0, m_settings[0]);` it does show the first line.

Comment: I have transfered the error to a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933961/c-output-parameter-index1-too-high-or-too-low-for-component)

Answer (score 1):

```
m_settings = m_settings_temp
    .Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string m_settings_temp;
string[] m_settings;
public void ShowSettingsGui()
{
    var dialog = new OpenFileDialog { Filter = "Data Sources (*.ini)|*.ini*|All Files|*.*" };
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;

    m_settings_temp = File.ReadAllText(dialog.FileName);
    m_settings = m_settings_temp.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
}
```