# C#: Output Parameter Index[i] too high or too low for Component

Tags: c#, parameters, grasshopper

The following error message appears when running the code below:

> c#: Output Parameter Index[1] too high or too low for Component.

The `IGH_DataAccess` is already providing an iteration count in the help it says *"Gets the current iteration count"*. The first time the `SolveInstance()` function is called on a component during a solution the Iteration counter will be zero. It will be incremented by one for every subsequent call. When using `DA.SetData(0, m_settings[0]);` it does show the first line.

The error message appears in the program used and I get the following exception on `DA.SetData(i, m_settings[i]);`:

`System.Exception occurred
  Message=Unknown file
  Source=Grasshopper
  StackTrace:
       at Grasshopper.Global_Proc.ASSERT(Guid assert_id, String message, Exception exception) in C:\dev\Grasshopper\1.0\root\src\GH_GlobalProc.vb:line 98
  InnerException:`

Herafter is the description of the IGH_DataAccess.SetData Method: `Stores data in an output parameter during GH_Component.SolveInstance(). Use this function only for setting individual data items. If you want to set lists of data, you *must* call SetDataList() instead.`

When changing the code to `DA.SetDataList(i, m_settings[i]);` the characters of the first line get split while I want every line to get split.

What am I doing wrong?

```
string[] m_settings;

public void ShowSettingsGui()
{
    var dialog = new OpenFileDialog { 
                     Filter = "Data Sources (*.ini)|*.ini*|All Files|*.*" };
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
    m_settings = File.ReadAllLines(dialog.FileName);
    ExpireSolution(true);
}

protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA)
{
    if (m_settings == null)
    {
        AddRuntimeMessage(GH_RuntimeMessageLevel.Warning, 
                          "You must declare some valid settings");
        return;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < m_settings.Length; i++)
    {
        DA.SetData(i, m_settings[i]);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where does the error message appear? If there is an exception please provide the exception including the stack trace.

Comment: @MartinLiversage thank you, I have added the information

Comment: Are you sure the file you read had 10 lines?

Comment: @BugFinder sorry I did this to test my code, I corrected the code in the question.

Comment: @MartinLiversage this is the line[1] of the file being loaded: `bed_size = 200,200` whereas the first line is `acceleration = 0` could this be the problem?

Comment: line[1] is not the first line, line[0] is the first line.. Do they not match?

Comment: @BugFinder this is what I was trying to say: line[0] of the ini is `acceleration = 0` and the second line line[1] is `bed_size = 200,200` can this create a problem?

Comment: You would need to post it as part of the code, at the moment it sounds like its read it right, are you asking if the comma would throw your parser?

Comment: @BugFinder you want me to post the ini file content as part of my code? I have just added some of this info to the question.

Comment: As your statements are vague. Yes, given an example of your input, as at themoment you've asked if 2 lines are a problem, how would we know? What does setdata do? when you trace it I cant see the line numbers wouldnt match from the code there.

Comment: @BugFinder sorry I really thought my question was precise, below is the explaination for IGH_DataAccess.setdata method: `Stores data in an output parameter during GH_Component.SolveInstance(). Use this function only for setting individual data items. If you want to set lists of data, you *must* call SetDataList() instead.` I guess the answer is there with the SetDataList() :)

Comment: Oddly enough, that doesnt help - you are asking us how your data effects code we cant see. If you also have one that handles lists - why bother sending line by line?

Comment: @BugFinder I am really sorry but I don't understand which code you cannot see?

Comment: As I said. You asked us if 2 specific lines would cause problems, line1 : "accelration = 0" and line2 "bed_size = 200,200" .. you call setdata - code you have not listed. How can you expect us to answer if this will cause problems?

Comment: @BugFinder I understand now but Setdata is part of the Kernel of a software so I cannot access it either and I put these two lines because the code throws an exception after the first one so I thought it might help.

Comment: Then Im guessing it hasnt accepted 200,200, and probably wants an integer, not comma separated values.

Comment: Hi @BugFinder it is an array of string so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Detailing where in grasshopper the exception is thrown is useless, you need to detail where in *your code* the exception occurs.

Comment: @PeterRitchie thanks but isn't that what I did when I wrote: " I get the following exception on DA.SetData(i, m_settings[i]);: " ?

Comment: @athurmani I think you're missing my point. I cant make it much more clear.. "SetData" does something with the text you're sending it.. what happens if you remove the comma does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by using the following code, replacing the SetData by SetDatalist with no loop and a different way of splitting the strings:

```
  string m_settings_temp;
            string[] m_settings;
            public void ShowSettingsGui()
            {
                var dialog = new OpenFileDialog { Filter = "Data Sources (*.ini)|*.ini*|All Files|*.*" };
                if (dialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;

                m_settings_temp = File.ReadAllText(dialog.FileName);
                m_settings = m_settings_temp.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                ExpireSolution(true);
            }



            protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA)
            {
                if (m_settings == null)
                {
                    AddRuntimeMessage(GH_RuntimeMessageLevel.Warning, "You must declare some valid settings");
                    return;
                }

                else

                {  
                        DA.SetDataList(0, m_settings);
                }  

            }
```